# employee count having difficulties

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following table, I am trying to find the following statement: For each employee, show how many employee(s) each supervises?

```
NAME                SSN       BDATE     SEX     SALARY SUPERSSN  DNO
------------------- --------- --------- --- ---------- --------- --------
John B Smith        123456789 09-JAN-55 M        30000 333445555 5
Franklin T Wong     333445555 08-DEC-45 M        40000 888665555 5
Alicia J Zelaya     999887777 19-JUL-85 F        25000 987654321 4
Jennifer S Wallace  987654321 20-JUN-31 F        43000 888665555 4
Ramesh K Narayan    666884444 15-SEP-52 M        38000 333445555 5
Joyce A English     453453453 31-JUL-62 F        25000 333445555 5
Ahmad V Jabbar      987987987 29-MAR-59 M        25000 987654321 4
James E Borg        888665555 10-NOV-27 M        55000
```

I can find the employees and supervisors but do not know how to count them:

```
SQL> select e.name, s.name, count(*) from jps.employee e, jps.employee s where e.superssn = s.ssn group by e.name, s.name; 

NAME                NAME                  COUNT(*)
------------------- ------------------- ----------
Ahmad V Jabbar      Jennifer S Wallace           1
Joyce A English     Franklin T Wong              1
Alicia J Zelaya     Jennifer S Wallace           1
Jennifer S Wallace  James E Borg                 1
Franklin T Wong     James E Borg                 1
John B Smith        Franklin T Wong              1
Ramesh K Narayan    Franklin T Wong              1
```

From the results above, you can see Franklin have 3 employees he supervises. How do i count them?

Thank you in advance,
Nils.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "GROUP BY" function using Name column (in your case either e.name or s.name).

For more info., u can go through this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Aggregate-Functions/ExampleusingtheCOUNTfunctionwithgroupbyclause.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I find this example: [Counting child for parent](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/counting-parents-and-children-with-count-distinct) and i think that is the solution:

`SQL> select s.name, count(e.name) from jps.employee e, jps.employee s where e.superssn = s.ssn group by s.name;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(E.NAME) AS ENAME,  S.NAME
FROM JPS.EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN JPS. EMPLOYEE S 
ON E.SUPERSSN = S.SSN
GROUP BY  S.NAME
```

Comment: Perhaps you can also explain how and why this statement works.

Comment: will give you the supervisor name (s.name) along with the count of people who he is in charge (e.name)